# Getting an error when trying to use UpsertDE() in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

I am getting an error when I try to upsert into the Data Extension using SSJS.

Error says : Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.

Here is the same code for which I get error:

```
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("Core","1");
  try{
    var rows = Platform.Function.UpsertDE("myDE",["fileName"],["fileName"]);
  }
  catch(e){
    Write("error"+e)
  }
</script>
```

The Data Extension exists and also has the field name. Could anyone guide me what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[UpsertDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformDataExtensionUpsertDE.html)** requires 5 parameters in the function call and you only have 3.

You have:

- The target DE
- The field array to filter on
- The value array to filter on

but are missing:

- The field array to add/update
- The value array to add/update

Likely this is what is causing your issue as you are not correctly using the function.  Your function should look more like below:

```js
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("Core","1");
  try{
    var rows = Platform.Function.UpsertDE("myDE",["fileName"],["fileName"],["field1","field2"],["val1","val2"]);
  }
  catch(e){
    Write("error"+e)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much and now it works.